# When does the forgetful functor from modules to vector spaces have a right adjoint?

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules, adjoint-functors

Given any algebra $R,$ when does the forgetful functor 
$R\text{-}Mod \rightarrow Vec$
have  a *right* adjoint?
Does this imply any finiteness conditions on R?
Is there a book/paper discussing this?

I've assumed $R$ is $k$ algebra where $k$ is a field. but if $k$ is not a field, and just a commutative ring then Marco's answer should hold up still with replacing $Vec$ by $k-Mod$.

Comment: I don't understand why this forgetful functor exists, e.g. if $R=\mathbb{Z}$. Are you assuming $R$ is an algebra over some field $k$? And Vec is the category of vector spaces over $k$?

Comment: I have written algebra in the question, just not the $k$s.

Comment: Well, "algebra" doesn't always mean algebra over a field.

Comment: Technically Very true, in my mind it always is, Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: I beleive marco's answer still holds thou

Answer (score 5):

Hom is right adjoint to tensor product. Have you tried to write the forgetfull functor as $F(M)=R\otimes_R M$?

I didn't check the details, but I think you can do something like

$$Hom_k(Forget(M),W)=Hom_k(M,W)\cong Hom_k(R\otimes_RM,W)\cong Hom_R(M,Hom_k(R,W))$$
where $M$ is an $R$-module, $W$ is a vector space, and the $R$-structure on $Hom(R,W)$ is from the right structure of $R$, that is $(r\cdot f)(x)=f(xr)$.

Comment: Thank you Marco, I thought Hom(R,-) would work but couldn’t think of a good reason why.

Comment: Are you aware of a similar construction for the forgetful functor from $Forg : R-Comod \rightarrow Vec$ having a LEFT adjoint?

Comment: mmm.. that seems more dificult. Now $R$ is a coalgebra, if $M$ is a (right) comodule then $M$ is a (left) $R^*$-module, and

Comment: mmm.. that seems more dificult. Now $R$ is a coalgebra, if $M$ is a (right) comodule then $M$ is a (left) $R^*$-module via $\phi\cdot m=\phi(m_1)m_0$, and $Hom^R(N,M)=Hom_{R^*}(N,M)$  for every pair of comodules $M,N$. On the other side, we know that $$Hom_k(V,M)\cong Hom_{R^*}(R^*\otimes V,M)$$ but $R^*\otimes V$ is not rational in general (i.e. is not  an $R^*$-module comming from an $R$-module, unless $R$ is finite dimensional), so, if it exists, I could try $(R^*\otimes V)_{rat}$, maybe $R^0\otimes V$, but it looks hard to work.

Comment: I believe the answer to this question is in Prop 31 of https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.pjm/1102868049

Comment: It is equivalent to R being finitely projective as a k module